# Как прибавлять +1 к первичному ключу, при добавлении данных в DataGrid?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Чтобы не возникала подобная проблема

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException
  HResult=0x80131501
  Сообщение = При обновлении записей возникла ошибка. Дополнительные сведения приведены во внутреннем исключении.
  Источник = EntityFramework
  Трассировка стека:
  Изначально это исключение было создано в этом стеке вызовов: 
    [Внешний код]

Внутреннее исключение 1:
UpdateException: При обновлении записей возникла ошибка. Дополнительные сведения приведены во внутреннем исключении.

Внутреннее исключение 2:
SqlException: Конфликт инструкции DELETE с ограничением REFERENCE "FK_ListOfTests_Teacher". Конфликт произошел в базе данных "ХолчукУПТеорияВероятностей", таблица "dbo.ListOfTests", column 'ID_Teacher'.
Выполнение данной инструкции было прервано.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Строка начинается с 1, но когда добавляю через

```
private void AddTeacher_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ХолчукУПТеорияВероятностейEntities1.GetContext().Teacher.Add(_currentTeacher);
    try
    {
        ХолчукУПТеорияВероятностейEntities1.GetContext().SaveChanges();
        MessageBox.Show("Данные успешно сохранены!");
        NavigationService.Navigate(new PageAdmin_Menu_Teacher());
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException Ex)
    {
        foreach (DbEntityValidationResult validationError in Ex.EntityValidationErrors)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Object: " + validationError.Entry.Entity.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show("");

            foreach (DbValidationError err in validationError.ValidationErrors)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.ErrorMessage + "");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

то следующий пользователь нулевой, и видимо дальше должен идти 1. но строка с таким первичным ключом уже существует и выходит ошибка.
Под 0 строка, которая была добавлена с помощью кода, описанного выше.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как исправить код?

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: изменил вопрос, может для наглядности нужно еще что-то показать?

Comment: Ключ в бд инкрементный?  Если нет, попробуйте включить.

Comment: Как это сделать? Я зашел в sql, попробовать включить спецификацию идентификатора, с начальным значение 1 и шаг приращения 1, теперь выходит другая ошибка: SqlException: Невозможно вставить явное значение для столбца идентификаторов в таблице "Teacher", когда параметр IDENTITY_INSERT имеет значение OFF.

Comment: ID больше не надо передавать, возможно передаете до сих пор его, поэтому и ругается имхо

Comment: @OwDafuq если включен автоинкремент, индекс инкрементируется, игнорируя переданное значение,

Comment: Ваш вопрос никак не связан ни с Visual Studio, ни с датагридом. Начните с того, что укажите точную версию используемого EF. Покажите модели сущностей и связи между ними. Тогда можно будет что-то посоветовать.